# Download files as attachement with .zip archieve

Tags: php, file, loops, zip, download

I am having this function in my class name MyMethods:

```
function zipDownload($file_names,$file_path){
    $zip_file_name = date('Y-m-d-h-i-s').'_attachement.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($zip_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        echo("cannot open <".$zip_file_name.">\n");     
        }
    else{
        $filePathAry = explode("/",$file_path);
        $count = count($filePathAry);
        $path = '';
        for($i=0; $i<=$count - 2; $i++){
            $path .= $filePathAry[$i].'/';
            }
        $path = $this->baseDir().$path;
        foreach($file_names as $files){
            $zip->addFile($path,$files);
            }
        $zip->close();      
        header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$zip_file_name); 
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
        header("Expires: 0"); 
        readfile($zip_file_name);
        exit;   
        }   
    }
```

I am calling this by the following code from presentation layer:

```
//filled array with names of files:
loop over files name{
         $filesAry[] = $fileName;
         }
$method->zipDownload($filesAry,$zipPath);
```

on debugging i get this link as an individual file path:

```
 Path : http://localhost/sites/mySite/bdc/uploader/exhibitsFiles/06_08_2014
 File Name: xyb.jpg
```

after clicking on the download all file as attachment, it produces .zip file but it does not open as normal .zip file?

What i am missing? please help me in this. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filesystem path rather than an http url in `$zip->addFile()` and make sure the file you're adding exists and is readable.

If you must grab the file to be added to the archive over http, use something along the lines of:

```
$zip->addFromString($files, file_get_contents($path));
```

in place of:

```
$zip->addFile($path,$files);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i have changed the code little different than old one but the idea is one of the same you added in the solution. Its working for me. i have checked it. thanks